# Android HttpUrlConnection returns 500

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, openweathermap

I'm trying to access open weather api using android. I used two methods, one for creating url and one for getting http response.

**Creating url**

```
 public static String API_LINK="http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";

 public static  String apiRequest(String lat, String lng){
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(API_LINK)
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("lat", lat)
                .appendQueryParameter("lon", lng)
                .appendQueryParameter("appid", API_KEY)
                .build();
        sb.append(builtUri.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

**Http request**

```
public String getHTTPData(String urlString){
        try {
            URL url=new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            Log.d("Helper", httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()+"");

            if(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()==200){//ok=200
                BufferedReader r=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line=r.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(line);
                    stream=sb.toString();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return stream;

    }
```

And i used a asyncTask to call this method in MainActivity

```
new GetWeather().execute(apiRequest("65.9667","-18.5333"));
```

But every time I make a request I get 500 http response code. I tried to navigate created url using browser, It's working. It not worked in my emulator.

How can i solve this. Thank you

Comment: That is an internal server error, it could be the server's fault.

Comment: But i can access the same url using browser

Comment: Have you by any means not used the OpenWeatherMap API key?

Comment: No i used the api key

Comment: I will try out your method of fetching the data and see the results

Answer (score 0):

[**500 Internal Server Error**](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1)

> The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from
>   fulfilling the request.

Its may be **`SERVER`** fault .This error can only be resolved by fixes to the Web server.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i can access the same url using browser

Comment: If you can access the same url using browser, make sure you add the correct params and headers to your request. That's all you can do since its a server side error.

Comment: @MudithaHasanka Facing problem yet ?